# Newsletter Bot Subscriber- How can protect site with this attack

Tags: newsletter, magento-1.14

When we check the server log and know that someone subscribes newsletter with

> 188.92.74.189 - - [01/Jan/2019:03:09:06 -0500] "POST /newsletter/subscriber/new/ HTTP/1.1" 302 - "SITE_URL" "Mozilla/5.0
>   (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko"
>
> SITE_URL is current site base URL only.

This is bot subscriber [Check](https://www.abuseipdb.com/check/188.92.74.189)

I have to write log and know that BOT send POST data like`

```
(
    [email] => dubbeld535@gmail.com
    [form_key] => Z1duNZ5JgtcQ97VM
)
```

- All security patch installed
- Google recaptcha already added to form.
- Added Form_key on form and validate on the controller.

Did anyone know that How Bot can validate form_key?
They are sending POST request directly to the controller, so Google recaptcha doesn't work on this.